# database lookup expedition using externally provided statistics during initialization

Tags: sqlite, database-performance, huffman-code

I have a large table that I can not fit to the memory. I am considering moving the table to a database, for example sqlite. However, the some of the lookups will be made very often, therefore they could stay in memory and rest could stay in the hard disk. I want to expedit the table lookup by supplying some statistics during initialization, so that memory lookups to the hard disk will be reduced. I have tried it with sqlite, however, I am not able to supply it a list of external statistics. Any suggestions?
Thank you,

Comment: Are you talking about the index statistics tables created by `ANALYZE`?

Comment: SQLite does not have any form of table value compression.

Comment: No, you could consider a handmade list

Comment: @DanD. so, what db does support this?